# Equivalent of subprocess.STARTUPINFO() in Mac?

Tags: python

I have this script that does some data cleaning to what netstat prints and it works absolutely fine in Windows. However, since [the STARTUPINFO class is only available in Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-popen-helpers) I'm not sure how do it for Mac OSX.

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
current_conecctions = subprocess.Popen("netstat -anot",shell = False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=si).stdout.read()
cleanConections(current_conecctions)
```

What would be the equivalent of this on Mac?

Comment: There is no need for `STARTUPINFO()` in `macOS`; it's not the same type of `OS` as `Windows` and there is no equivalent. `Popen()` usually handles everything perfectly fine on `*NIX` based systems without requiring any "helpers". Generally if you're attempting to show a window then using `Tkinter` or similar is what is recommended.

Comment: Is there a an equivalent to current_conecctions = subprocess.Popen("netstat -anot",shell = False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=si).stdout.read() using tkinter?